# Doesn't Yaakov have רוח הקודש

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, nevua-prophecy, vayeitzei

In this week's parsha (Bereishit 31:32), Yaakov says that whoever stole Lavan's idols will not live, not knowing that Rochel had taken them. Doesn't Yaakov have רוח הקודש he should have known that it was Rochel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard 2 answers to this question. Do not remember sources.

1 - Since the Terafim were in the tent, the Tumah (impurity) blocked Yaakov's Ruach Hakodesh.

2 - Yaakov was married to 2 sisters, which is forbidden by the Torah. One of the reasons it was allowed was that the Avos did not keep the Torah in Chutz Laretz. Yaakov was on his way back to Eretz Yisrael, and there the Avos did keep the Torah. Hashem made this happen as one of his wives had to die prior to entering Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: So then why did G-D kill Leah G-D knew Yaakov liked rochel better?

Comment: הכוונה ליעקב שלא הוליך אותה למערה כדי שלא יקבור שם שתי אחיות, כי יבוש מאבותיו. ולאה היא הנשאת לו ראשונה בהיתר, ורחל באהבתו אותה בנדר אשר נדר לה לקחתה.
(פרק מ"ח, פסוק ז').
לפי דברי הרמב"ן, קבורתה של רחל בדרך לא הייתה במקרה, בגלל מותה בדרך: רחל לא נקברה במערת המכפלה מפני שיעקב הרגיש שאין זה ראוי שהוא ייקבר עם שתי אחיות ששתיהן נשותיו , ורחל נפטרה בכניסה לארץ מפני שבארץ לא ראוי להיות נשוי לשתי אחיות. דווקא רחל היא זו שמתה ולא לאה, כיוון שלאה היא אשתו הראשונה ולכן הנישואין איתה יותר ראויים, ואילו בנישואין עם רחל יש פגם בארץ ישראל. 
http://etzion.vbm-torah.org/

Comment: @yehudasneidz I explained why Rachel was the one to die at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48699/when-yaakov-said-whoever-stole-the-idols-will-not-live-was-that-a-curse-or-vo/48700#48700 Since Rachel was in danger (due to childbirth) she was judged then and died.

Comment: `Since the Terafim were in the tent, the Tumah (impurity) blocked Yaakov's Ruach Hakodesh` What tumah? Why were the terafim tameh?

Answer (score 5):

Even a full blown Navi only gets the the messages Hashem sends and regarding anything else can be mistaken. See Taanya, Igeres Hakodesh chapter 22.

Otherwise they would all be millionaires.

Comment: "Otherwise they would all be millionaires": if they were interested in becoming millionaires, which presumably people on such a rarefied level aren't particularly. So that argument is weak at best.

Comment: It was anecdotal. But if you need to be hyperliteral about it, just think of all the poor people they could fed.

Comment: Also, a prerequisite to nevuah was to be rich.